# RSA signature verification failed using Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I am new to crypto++ and building my first app that needs to follow OOP concepts for me to build further.

Can you spot what is wrong because of which verifysignature function below is returning false?

Mysample app has a Wallet for each user where users can send some money to another user's wallet. I created a wallet class and in constructor instantiated RSA::Public and RSA::PrivateKey. I created a transaction class which saves signature created using PrivateKey of sender. But while verifying the signature using public key of the sender, the verfication fails.

```
// Wallet Constructor
Wallet::Wallet()
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // Pseudo Random Number Generator
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // Generate Parameters
    CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 3072);

    m_privateKey = CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey(params);
    m_publicKey = CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey(params);
   }

std::string Signature::SignData(std::string data, CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey senderPrivateKey    )
{
    std::string signature("");

    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
    Signer signaturePen(senderPrivateKey);
    CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 3072);

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(data, true,
        new CryptoPP::SignerFilter(rng, signaturePen,
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(signature)));
    return signature;
}

bool Signature::VerifySignature(CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey senderPublicKey,
        const std::string &data,
        const std::string &SignatureStr)
{
    Verifier  signatureVerifier(senderPublicKey);

    // verify message
    bool result = false;

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(data+SignatureStr, true,
        new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(signatureVerifier,
            new CryptoPP::ArraySink((CryptoPP::byte*)&result,
                sizeof(result))));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The question is missing all the security parameters, like public key, private key, message and signature. Maybe [RSA Signature Schemes](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes) from the wiki will be helpful.

Comment: Thnx Jww! I experimented and instead of passing data+messagestr to the function call(as given in crypto wiki), I passed messagestr+data. This worked fine and the verification succeeded.  
    `CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(** SignatureStr+data **, true,
    new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(signatureVerifier,
     new CryptoPP::ArraySink((CryptoPP::byte*)&result,
      sizeof(result))));`